# Hide div on jsp page when back browser button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, back

Well I have a "jsp1" which contains a div with a button. Once the div button is pressed, it takes me to the next "jsp2". However, if the "back" browser button is clicked, I need the div button on "jsp1" to be hidden and prevent the user from click it, and if possible show other div that is already hidden. How can I achieve this using no frameworks.

piece "jsp1":

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test = "${submissionButtonSwitch == 1}">
<div> <!-- div i want to show after -->
<h2>This bill has already been submitted, go back to carry out a new purchase</h2>
</div>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<div class="buttonWrapper"> <!-- div I want to hide after -->
<input class="button" type = "submit" value = "SUBMIT">
</div>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

[image: DIV BUTTON]

As you can see, I tried to get the result that I want through JSTL server side operations, but after a while I think this has more to do with JavaScript, than any other thing.
I would be really glad to any suggestion, Im kind of beginner with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add load event to check navigation status `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === "back_forward"` if browser back clicked then show/hide components:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if(performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === "back_forward"){
        // show hide components
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to change "window.performance.navigation.type === 2" by "performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === "back_forward"", since compiler indicates me that ".navigation.type" is deprecated.

but jsp still shows me both DIVS, i dont know if i have to call the function on my jsp or just by adding "<script type="text/javascript" src="js/billFrontScript.js"> async</script>" in tag <head> I get it working, and hence i'd be still doing something wrong

Comment: I think this issue occurred when your code set onload event more than one . I edited my answer to use `addEventListener` function to prevent that conflict. Just check it!

Comment: And i edited to use `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type` to check browser back based on your recommended.

Comment: window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if(performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === "back_forward"){
        document.getElementById("adviceWrapper").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("buttonWrapper").style.display = "block";
    }
})

This is what i've added but still nothing :/

Comment: i dont know what happend with that code, i tested on local, all of that code working perfectly. You can download sample here https://drive.google.com/file/d/16xAy3UAonwBnPOK8_M7pqSRQeE79_tGE/view?usp=sharing